# How to properly use runif and rnorm to make an equation for a variable?

Tags: r, variables, equation

How to properly use runif and rnorm to fit an nls model with a starting value?

Here is a sample code:

```
set.seed(5000)
x<-seq(0,50,1)
y<-runif(1,5,15)*exp(-runif(1,0.01,0.05)*x)+rnorm(51,0,0.5)
plot(x,y)
```

I don't have any idea how the equation was formed using runif and rnorm on the variable 'y'.

Thank you for the improvements and responses.

Comment: Are you asking how this code works?

Comment: Yes @mcz. Sorry if my point on the question is not that clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can split the `y` formula into four parts:

1) `runif(1,5,15)` picks a single (`1`) number from a uniform distribution ranging from `5` to `15`.  This single number is multiplied by all the 51 output elements of #3 below, so it drives the general height of the curve.

2) `runif(1,0.01,0.05)` picks a single (`1`) number from a uniform distribution ranging from `0.01` to `0.05`. This number is multiplied by x and put into the exponential function in #3, so it drives the rate of descent of the curve.

3) #2 is put inside a larger term that multiplies the single number from #2 by each of the values of x, which in this case is a vector with 51 elements from 0 to 50, and that in turn is put into the `exp` exponential function. This is the part that generates the general exponential decay shape of the plot.

4) the last `+rnorm(51,0,0.5)` sprinkles some normally distributed noise by creating a vector with 51 elements, each of which is from a distribution with a mean of 0 and SD of 0.5.

So this equation simulates an exponential decay with 51 elements. The first term determines the height, the 2nd the slope, and the fourth element adds some noise to that.

Comment: Is there any restrictions on how to make a equation for a variable using runif and rnorm?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking what parameters were put into the equation that generated the sample data? Can you explain more what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes. Also, I'm curious how runif and rnorm affects the variables x and y when I plot them. I used to change the mean and SD also the n then analyze the plot, yet still I don't understand how runif and rnorm works mathematically. Thank You.

Comment: x in this case is just the 51 integers from 0 to 50. `runif` and `rnorm` are functions which give you pseudo-random numbers. Type `?runif` and `?rnorm` for the help docs for these. Those answer many questions with careful reading.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is already an accepted answer, the question also asks about a non linear `nls` fit.

Here is a way of doing it.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x, y)

cat("a.true:", a, " b.true:", b, "\n")
#a.true: 9.482203  b.true: 0.02768012

nls(y ~ a*exp(-b*x), df1, start = list(a = 5, b = 1))
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ a * exp(-b * x)
#   data: df1
#      a       b 
#9.28448 0.02636 
# residual sum-of-squares: 9.493
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 9.938e-08
```

Since the formula is not very complex and it can be transformed in a formula linear in `x`, such as `log(y) = log(a) - b*x`, the standard linear model can give other estimates of the parameters `a` and `b`. Note that a negative `b` is estimated.

```
fit2 <- lm(log(y) ~ x, df1)
log.a <- coef(fit2)[1]
neg.b <- coef(fit2)[2]
cat("a.lm:", exp(log.a), " b.lm:", -neg.b, "\n")
#a.lm: 9.293966  b.lm: 0.0266301
```

**Data.**

Data creation code repeated, this time with the two parameters `a` and `b` explicitly created.

```
set.seed(5000)
x <- seq(0, 50, 1)
a <- runif(1, 5, 15)
b <- runif(1, 0.01, 0.05)
y <- a*exp(-b*x) + rnorm(51, 0, 0.5)
```

Comment: I forget that I also asked about the nls fit, since I focused on runif and rnorm. Also, you provided transformation of the formula. Thank for the responses. That would be a great help.